# apply map to tf dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def scale(X,  dtype='float32'):
    a=-1
    b=1
    xmin = tf.cast(tf.math.reduce_min(X), dtype=dtype)
    xmax = tf.cast(tf.math.reduce_max(X), dtype=dtype)
    X = (X - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)
    scaled = X * (b - a) + a
    return scaled, xmin, xmax

a = np.random.random((20, 4, 4, 2)).astype('float32')
b = np.random.random((20, 16, 16, 2)).astype('float32')

dataset_a = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a)
dataset_b = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(b)

dataset_ones = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.ones((len(b), 4, 4, 1)))   

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_a, (dataset_b, dataset_ones)))

dataset = dataset.map(scale)
```

Can I somehow apply map to the above dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When zipping multiple datasets, the resulting dataset will have elements as tuples. However, the scale function is expecting a single tensor as input, not a tuple.

To fix the issue, you need to modify the code to handle the tuple elements correctly.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def scale(X, dtype='float32'):
    a = -1
    b = 1
    xmin = tf.cast(tf.math.reduce_min(X), dtype=dtype)
    xmax = tf.cast(tf.math.reduce_max(X), dtype=dtype)
    X = (X - xmin) / (xmax - xmin)
    scaled = X * (b - a) + a
    return scaled, xmin, xmax

a = np.random.random((20, 4, 4, 2)).astype('float32')
b = np.random.random((20, 16, 16, 2)).astype('float32')

dataset_a = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(a)
dataset_b = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(b)
dataset_ones = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.ones((len(b), 4, 4, 1)))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_a, dataset_b, dataset_ones))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y, z: (scale(x), scale(y), z))
```

In the above code, the datasets dataset_a, dataset_b, and dataset_ones are zipped together using tf.data.Dataset.zip(). Then, the map() function is used with a lambda function to apply the scale() function to each element in the dataset. The lambda function unpacks the tuple elements (x, y, z), applies the scale() function to x and y, and keeps z unchanged.

Now, the dataset.map() operation should work correctly without raising the type conversion error.